# sqlite3 node_module bloat

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

A fresh install of Electron (v21.2.2 win32-x64) using npm to install sqlite3 node package v5.1.2 shows when I open the node_module folder 101 items. I deleted them all except for sqlite3 and console now shows dependency errors :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@mapbox/node-pre-gyp'
Require stack:
- D:\Electron\resources\app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js
- D:\Electron\resources\app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
.....
```

I understand there are dependencies from the sqlite3 package.json, specifically node-pre-gyp. However out of 101 packages it wants 28 just to run sqlite3:

- @mapbox/node-pre-gyp
- abbrev
- ansi-regex
- aproba
- are-we-there-yet
- color-support
- console-control-strings
- delegates
- detect-libc
- emoji-regex
- gauge
- has-unicode
- inherits
- is-fullwidth-code-point
- lru-cache
- nopt
- npmlog
- object-assign
- readable-stream
- semver
- set-blocking
- signal-exit
- sqlite3
- string-width
- strip-ansi
- util-deprecate
- wide-align
- yallist

I wanted sqlite3 for Electron and was expecting one module. Are they all needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unsatisfying answer is **Yes**.

> ... unsure if they are all truly needed?

The short explanation is that `npm` is *designed to work this way*; different packages have their own dependency tree, which have their own, and so on...

As you have found, doing this will break packages:

> I deleted them all except for sqlite3 and console shows dependency errors

**It is wise to leave the `node_modules/` directory alone**

###### Side Note

As you use more external libraries, you may begin to see the number of dependencies doesn't continue to grow at the same rate. This is because some libraries will have the similar (or the same) underlying dependency tree.

This is where package managers really come into their own.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, its basically a daisy chain of dependencies which makes sense but looks like bloat for those that do not know

Comment: @ChezskyNoname that's very true, and it is alarming the way it looks when you first open it. Take solace that it's ultimately designed to be more machine-readable. It can provide debugging help if you run into dependency issues between different packages that require specific versions of the same underlying package, but those are rare early on...